# Options for calling a usb card reader from asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

A project I am working on was given the task of calling an usb emv card reader from the web (Magtek DynaMag).  The site I am working with is asp.net (4.5).

I realize that this can be done via java, or Silverlight (or if I was fine with an asp classic page via an active x control, however my options are limited as the only way I have to call the reader is a .dll file that was made to be consumed by a win forms device, and outside of c# I am not to familiar with other languages. I saw options about using a Windows Form Control Library online but the samples are back from 2004 – 06 and since then the technologies have changed.

The questions I have are as follows.
1.  Is a Win Form Control Lib still a viable option, and if so how do you add it to the asp site and display(code samples would be nice)
2.  If not, then what are my options and how do I go about implementing this dll into the asp.net site?

I realize that I may be limited to working with only IE (im fine with that) and as for reference;
**WFCL DLL name when built:** MagtekWFCL.dll

**Namespace:** MagtekWFCL

**Class:** BagOfHolding (it’s a garbage name in the test code as its holding all my junk code)

**How i am attempting to add it to the aspx page currently:**

```
<object id="TagReader" runat="server" height="476" width="428" data="MagtekWFCL.dll">
        </object>
```

**DLL i am getting from magtek:**[DynaPro.NET API](http://www.magtek.com/support/software/downloads/sw/99510092.exe)

Any help into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a year old but I just ran into this problem myself.  Magtek has a new project based on WPF/C# with updated documentation and new libraries for interfacing a reader through WPF, Winforms, or ASP.Net.  https://www.magtek.com/Content/SoftwarePackages/99510132.zip

Add the four DLL's to your project: MTDevice.dll, MTLIB.dll, MTSCRANET.dll, MTService.dll and a reference to them as well, then add these using statements:

```
using MTLIB;
using MTSCRANET;
```

and then a reference field:

```
private MTSCRA _SwipeScanner;
```

You can then access the reader like this:

```
    _SwipeScanner = new MTSCRA();
    _SwipeScanner.setConnectionType(MTConnectionType.USB);
    _SwipeScanner.openDevice();
```

You will then need to create events for when a card is swiped, card data changed, connection status changed, etc.

Also I found calling Magtek's customer service was pretty easy as well.  I had to leave a message but they called me back within a couple hours.  I doubt this will help you due to the age of the question, but hopefully it will help others.